# Use MomentJS to format date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I cannot get pikaday to work and return the date in the format I'm asking `moment.js` to produce.

```
var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('startdate'),
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
        maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
        yearRange: [2000,2020],
        onSelect: function(date) {

          conosle.log(moment(picker.toString(), "MM-DD-YYYY"));

        }

    });
```

http://jsbin.com/besatocafelo/1/edit

Also, how can I get the properly formatted date into the `input`.

Comment: Is it a typo `conosle`?

Comment: @renatoargh haha, yeah, typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to format a date with moment.js is:

```
yourMomentDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') //or whatever format you want
```

So you should fix it to;

```
console.log(moment(picker.toString(), "MM-DD-YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

Since Picker gives you a date object you can do;

```
console.log(moment(picker).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me an error. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What gives you an error is that you have a broken reference to moment.js

Answer (score 1):

you may pass a date object or date string to moment and then call format on it. I think what you're trying to do is this:

`moment(date).format("MM/DD/YY")`

or

`moment(picker.toString()).format("MM/DD/YY")`

**Note:** Your jsbin is missing a reference to momentJS, and has a typo on console.log